# Switching fragments within tab

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm creating an app that uses ActionBarSherlock. The app consists of three tabs, and in each of them, multiple screens are shown consecutively based on user input. I am able to switch Fragments between tabs, but the switching of fragments *within* tabs gives a problem. I've tried it like this:

In the main class:

```
SingleStationFragment singleStationFragment = new SingleStationFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, singleStationFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

This *does* replace the first fragment for the second, but when I change tabs, the second fragment is still visible, showing the content of the new tab on top of the content of the old tab. I think somehow I need to detach the second fragment in `onTabUnselected`, but I have no idea how to get a reference to this Fragment.

Can anyone help me with this?

For clarity, some significant classes:

My main class:

```
public class TreinVerkeer extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupTabs(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void setupTabs(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("STATIONS").setTabListener(new TabListener<StationsFragment>(this, "stations", StationsFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("ROUTE").setTabListener(new TabListener<RouteFragment>(this, "route", RouteFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("DELAYS").setTabListener(new TabListener<DelaysFragment>(this, "delays", DelaysFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }
}
```

The TabListener (from ["Adding Navigations Tabs" on the Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) with some minor changes):

```
public class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private SherlockFragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /**
     * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag
     *            The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz
     *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFragment == null && preInitializedFragment == null) {
        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
        mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else if (mFragment != null) {
        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    } else if (preInitializedFragment != null) {
        ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
        mFragment = preInitializedFragment;
    }
}

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

And `StationsFragment` (`RouteFragment` and `DelaysFragment` are the same, with only different text)

```
public class StationsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.stationsfragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So what happened was that, in `TabListener`, in the `onTabUnselected` method, the `Fragment` was not detached, causing it to still be show while a new `Fragment` was shown.

The cause to this was, that the `Fragment` that was detached was the first fragment, and not my second fragment. I've made some changes.

In the `Activity`:

```
SingleStationFragment singleStationFragment = new SingleStationFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, singleStationFragment, "STATIONS");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Here I've added the `"STATIONS"` tag in the `replace()` method, which is the same tag as the first fragment.
The `TabListener` is now as follows:

```
public class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    private SherlockFragment mFragment;

    public TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (preInitializedFragment == null) {
            mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.treinverkeer_fragmentcontent, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

        if (preInitializedFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(preInitializedFragment);
        } else if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

In the `onTabUnselected` method I now first retrieve the correct `Fragment`, then detach it.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Could you please send me some code, this is exactly what i am trying to do.